# What value from memory or register do each of the AT&T syntax operands access?

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-address, att, addressing-mode

Assume the following values are stored at the indicated memory addresses and registers:

```
Address    Value            Register     Value
0x100      0xFF             %eax         0x100
0x104      0xAB             %ecx         0x1
0x108      0x13             %edx         0x3
0x10C      0x11


Fill in the following table showing the values for the indicated operands:

Operand           Value    //Solutions at the end of the chapter
%eax              _____    //0x100
0x104             _____    //0xAB
$0x108            _____    //0x108
(%eax)            _____    //0xFF
4(%eax)           _____    //0xAB
9(%eax, %edx)     _____    //0x11
260(%ecx, %edx)   _____    //0x13
0xFC(,%ecx,4)     _____    //0xFF
(%eax, %edx,4)    _____    //0x11
```

Can someone explain to me how to do this in layman's terms. This isn't hmwk (it's practice problems during certain readings which have the answers @ the end of the chapter), I'm just not understanding the reading.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The general rule for AT&T x86 assembly syntax is

```
displacement(offset, relative offset, multiplier) = offset + displacement + ( relative offset * multiplier)
```

1. `%eax` refers to actual value of the register(=0x100).
2. `0x104` refers to the value at address 0x104.
3. `$0x108` refers to the constant value 0x108.
4. `(%eax)` refers to the value at address EAX, which is equivalent to 0x100(=0xFF).
5. `4(%eax)` refers to the value at address EAX+4, which is at 0x104.
6. `9(%eax, %edx)` refers to the value at address EAX+9 + EDX, which is at 0x10C.
7. `260(%ecx, %edx)` refers to the value at address ECX+260 + EDX, which is at 0x108.
8. `0xFC(,%ecx,4)` refers to the value at address (ECX*4)+0xFC, which is at 0x100.
9. `(%eax, %edx, 4)` refers to the value at address (EAX+(EDX*4), which is at 0x10C.

Comment: Much clearer... Still not understanding #7.. how can 1+ 4 + 260 = 0x108?

Comment: @CarlosCarrillo ecx is 1, edx is 3, so ECX+260+EDx=1+3+260=264=0x108

Comment: O ok, I have to convert from decimal to hex. the other problems I don't, that's where I got confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You need to learn this AT&T assembly syntax and a little bit of assembly and once you know that stuff, the answers are trivial.

So,

`%eax` is just the contents of the register.

`0x104` is a memory operand, the contents of the memory at address `0x104`.

`$0x108` is a constant.

`(some expression)` is a memory operand, the contents of the memory at address `some expression`.

`some constant(some expression)` is a memory operand, the contents of the memory at address `some expression` + `some constant`.

`(%register1, %register2)` is, as you may have guessed by now, also a memory operand. The value of the parenthesized expression is `register1` + `register2`.

`some constant(%register1, %register2)` should be trivial by now as well. Just add the three items and that's the address.

`(, %register, some constant)` means that you need to multiply the value of the register by the constant.

`(%register1, %register2, some constant)` should now be intuitive. The value of the parenthesized expression is `register1` + `register2` * `some constant`.

Guess now the address of the memory operand like this:

`some constant1(%register1, %register2, some constant2)`.